# Expand parent div according to inner div that has position: absolute

Tags: html, css

I would like to have my parent div to expand, according to its inner content.

The parent div has position relative, and the inner divs have position absolute.

```
<div id="parent" style="position:relative; border: 8px solid black;">
    <div id="child1" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 0px;></div>
    <div id="child2" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 100px; left: 0px;></div>
</div>
```

Is there a solution for this or should i restructure the code and move child2 to child1 place ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you positioning both of these child elements using `absolute`? The way they will appear in the layout right now would be the same if you placed them in as `static` or `relative`. `Absolute` positioning should only really be used for achieving unique style effects.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have such case, my solution is to set the parent's height in js code, here is the example http://chennanfei.iteye.com/blog/1333165.